# How to access attributes inside a variant column using snowflake-sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, query-builder

Using snowflake-sqlalchemy library, is there any i can access attributies inside a variant column and use them in queries?
Example :- If i have the following table,

```
example = Table('example', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('data', VARIANT)
)
```

and data is a variant column, how do i write a query to select an attribute of data, something like this :-

```
query = select(example.data['key'])
```

I tried multiple combinations :- `example.data['key']`, `example.data.key` and nothing seems to work. Is it possible at all in the first place? If so, how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

[Using the Snowflake SQLAlchemy Toolkit with the Python Connector - VARIANT, ARRAY, and OBJECT Support](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html#variant-array-and-object-support):

> Snowflake SQLAlchemy supports fetching **VARIANT**, ARRAY and OBJECT data types. All types are converted into str in Python so that you can convert them to native data types using **json.loads.**
>
> This example shows how to create a table including VARIANT, ARRAY, and OBJECT data type columns:
>
> ```
> from snowflake.sqlalchemy import (VARIANT, ARRAY, OBJECT)
> ...
> t = Table('my_semi_structured_datatype_table', metadata,
>     Column('va', VARIANT),
>     Column('ob', OBJECT),
>     Column('ar', ARRAY))
> metdata.create_all(engine)
> ```
>
> In order to retrieve VARIANT, ARRAY, and OBJECT data type columns and convert them to the native Python data types, fetch data and call the json.loads method as follows:
>
> ```
> import json
> connection = engine.connect()
> results = connection.execute(select([t]))
> row = results.fetchone()
> data_variant = json.loads(row[0])
> data_object  = json.loads(row[1])
> data_array   = json.loads(row[2])
> ```

Comment: Thanks. But my question was more like, how do i access the atributes the variant column, in a select query, with snowflake-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they haven't implemented the `__getitem__` style querying like postgres has (yet... this PR has been open for 2 years, so don't hold your breath: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/pull/245).

There are three workarounds I have found:

1. use the `GET` and `GET_PATH` functions to do the same thing: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html#extracting-values-using-the-get-function

   in your example, this should work, using `sqlalchemy.func`:

   ```py
   query = select(func.get(example.data, 'key'))
   ```
2. use the `.op(":")` operator function to use `:` style access:

   ```py
   query = select(example.data.op(":")(text("key"))
   ```
3. use the `snowflake-sqlalchemy-json` library, which monkey-patches the `SnowflakeCompiler` to support `__getitem__` compilation: https://github.com/masamitsu-murase/snowflake-sqlalchemy-json

   ```py
   import snowflake_sqlalchemy_json
   snowflake_sqlalchemy_json.register_json_handler()
   query = select(example.data['key'])
   ```